# bulk collect into table type of objects

Tags: oracle, plsql, object-type, bulk-collect

I got en error when attempting to use a `BULK COLLECT` statement `ORA-00947: not enough values` for table of objects.

Error occurs at the line `from (select jta.nobject_id,`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T_PPW_WORK"  as object                                     
    (          
      nObjectKey   number,  
      cJobType     varchar2(500),  
      dPlanStart   date,
      dPlanEnd     date,
      cExecutor    varchar2(500),
      cComment     varchar2(4000)
    )

    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T_PPW_WORK_TABLE" as table of T_PPW_WORK;                                         


      function getPlannedOverdueJobs(in_nPlanKey number) return T_PPW_WORK_TABLE is
        l_oWorks T_PPW_WORK_TABLE;    
        l_oWork T_PPW_WORK;    
      begin

        select * bulk collect
          into l_oWorks
          from (select jta.nobject_id,
                       jt.cjobtype_name,                           
                       jta.dactual_start,
                       jta.dactual_finish,
                       st.familiya,
                       jta.ccomment
                  from ppw_jobtype_assign jta
                  left join pgts_sotrudnik st
                    on jta.nworkerid = st.npgts_sotrudnikkey
                  join ppw_jobtype jt
                    on jta.njobtype_id = jt.njobtype_key);
        return l_oWorks;
      end getPlannedOverdueJobs;
```

what is the reason?

Answer (score 6):

```
    select * bulk collect
      into l_oWorks
      from (select t_ppw_work(jta.nobject_id,
                   jt.cjobtype_name,                           
                   jta.dactual_start,
                   jta.dactual_finish,
                   st.familiya,
                   jta.ccomment)
              from ppw_jobtype_assign jta
              left join pgts_sotrudnik st
                on jta.nworkerid = st.npgts_sotrudnikkey
              join ppw_jobtype jt
                on jta.njobtype_id = jt.njobtype_key);
```

You need to convert your result set using your defined object type (t_ppw_work) first.

Comment: how? I know how to do it when i have single set of data , but with multiset.

Comment: It is how you define the _single row_ of your result, with appropriate object usage.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like below instead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE  "F_OBJ" AS OBJECT (
Employee_name VARCHAR2(100),
Employee_id VARCHAR2 ( 100 ))

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE  "F_TAB" as table of F_OBJ

create or replace function "fname"
return f_tab
is
 l_f_tab f_tab;

begin
SELECT f_obj(employee_name, employee_id) bulk collect into f_tab from employee_table;
return f_tab;
end;
```